# Run pinned taskbar apps at windows startup?

Tags: windows, batch-file, autohotkey, startup

How to run all apps that are pinned to taskbar at startup?

Seems like an ideal feature. I pin apps because I click them all once windows logs in.

No luck with batch file:

```bash
for %1 in (%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.ink) do "%1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Loop Files, %A_AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.lnk
{
    FileGetShortcut, %A_LoopFileLongPath%, ShortcutTarget
    SplitPath, ShortcutTarget, , , , name
    Process, Exist, %name%.exe
    If (!ErrorLevel)
    {
        Run, %ShortcutTarget%
    }
}
return
```

This ended up being the best solution.